# dependencyOverrides causes sbt update times to go up by 4-5x

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

SBT **0.13.1** and Scala **2.10.3**.

We have implemented a plugin that sets the `dependencyOverrides` to standard artifact versions. My `dependencyOverrides` set is about 950 artifacts large. Not that we have all these dependencies but this is the standard versions people need to use.

After implementing the overrides, `sbt update` times (a reference project with 11 sub-projects) on Mac (Mac OS 10.7.5, Oracle JDK 1.7.0_45) jumped from **~30 seconds** to **~140 seconds**. The referenced artifacts are actually smaller as this gets rid of many duplicate artifacts of different versions.

I've run sbt under `-Xprof` to see what is the problem and found this major difference:

Before `dependencyOverrides`:

```
Compiled + native   Method                        
3.2%    10  +     0    org.apache.ivy.core.module.id.ModuleRules.getRules
```

After `dependencyOverrides`:

```
Compiled + native   Method                        
31.6%   136  +     2    org.apache.ivy.core.module.id.ModuleRules.getRules
```

`Xprof` doesn't give me invocation counts. But from a brief review of `ModuleRules.getRules` there seem to be not much complexity. That gives me a hint the invocation count may have skyrocketed. I'll have to use different profilers to get a better grip.

Unfortunately, Scala/SBT plugin for IntelliJ constantly causes a `sbt resolve` and the user experience is that much worse. I'd like to run this by others who may have run into this issue before or even know of a good way to fix it (short of diving into ivy code and figuring out the issue + modifying ivy code myself).

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: That's definitely a class in Ivy.  We've known Ivy to be slow, and I'd love to go to something faster/more powerful.   Unfortunately, the reality is that we're using Ivy so investments in speeding it up will help us out.

Comment: Note: in sbt 0.13.6-M1 there's some ivy performance improvements around getRules that you should check out.